# HP Touch Sreen does not have WIFI connection anymore

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver, wireless-adapter

I had a desktop (HP Touchsreen320 with Windows 7)  working for years. I turned it off, moved the computer to another room, and I guess the WIFI didn't like the move. 
I have spent so much time on this problem...
It has Cable Ethernet connection. It had wifi, not anymore. 
Things I have tried:

```
  1. Under Device Manager, Network adapters, we have only one option -
Realtec PCIe GBE Family Controller. Nothing else as we should expect

  2. Under Basic Network information and set up connections: 

   2a) The troubleshooter only tries to fix the cable, never the wifi.

  3. Set up a new connection => Connect to network => do you want to use a connection that you already have? => 
    there are 2 options, a) no, b) yes => there is only Broadband Connections WAN Miniport (PPOE). 

   3b. If I click on it and choose the broadband, I have "Type the info form you ISP - At this level, it does not accept my credentials on the Moden - native credentials working in other devices. It throws an error 651. 

  4. I called Uverse, and their opinion is that probably nothing related to the Modem. They suggested buying a new adaptor. 

  5. If I troubleshoot the adaptor or Internet connection, I only get the cable is the problem 
  6. Restore: the last one is the day I moved to another room: 2/13. 5 days ago. More dates and it shows that there was on windows update on the 13, but I am sure this happened after the problem
    6a) scan for affected problems: a few items, and HP support 8.5.37.19 & HP support solutions framework 12.8.47.1 (I am pretty sure this took place after the problem)
```

I am running out of skills to keep troubleshooting.
    Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS. I tried to install window 10, it goes through 100% and then there another round and then checking for updates forever. Tried twice. This was a computer with little use before. Wifi was good, however.
PS2 There is one critical update and then goes preparing to install and never ends.

Comment: "I...  moved... to another room." Did you test it afterwards back in the old location?

Comment: Yes, I did just for the heck of it. WiFi is gone

Comment: What do you mean by the Wifi was gone? Do you still see WLANs or is the WLAN adapter on the computer not working anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can try going into the bios and making sure your wireless card isn't disabled.

Some laptops have a key combo or a switch to turn the wireless card on and off. It's usually  fn key & whichever keyboard key has the wireless symbol.

You can try googling your models service manual and reseat the wireless card. If windows fails to recognize the card after trying these steps, it could be that you have a defective wireless nic in your computer. It's rare but does happen.

Hope this helps.